# How to prevent SSL renegotiation when using Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a pretty simple reverse proxy that should just proxy the requests to another domain. This fails because it attempts to SSL renegotiate, which is not allowed (as expected).

What can be the cause of this SSL renegotiation and how can I prevent it?

**Basic server info**

```
Debian release: 9.8 / stretch
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019)
TLS SNI support enabled
```

**Config**

```
upstream example {
        server test.example.com:443;
}

server {
        listen 443 http2;
        listen [::]:443 http2;

        ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/website/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website/fullchain.pem;

        #include snippets/global-ssl.conf;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://example;
                proxy_set_header Host test.example.com;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_ssl_name test.example.com;
        }
}
```

**Client logs (trimmed)**

```
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: accept on 0.0.0.0:443, ready: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: posix_memalign: 00005563F4DEDF70:512 @16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 accept: 213.126.45.75:54725 fd:40
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer add: 40: 60000:1553443042390
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 reusable connection: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 epoll add event: fd:40 op:1 ev:80002001
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http check ssl handshake
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http recv(): 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 ssl get session: BAE39B42:32
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL server name: "www.example.com"

==> /var/log/nginx/example_website_error.log <==
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL ALPN supported by client: h2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL ALPN supported by client: http/1.1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL ALPN selected: h2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL handshake handler: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 ssl new session: 00AE8065:32:174
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL: TLSv1.3, cipher: "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLSv1.3 Kx=any Au=any Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL reused session
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 init http2 connection
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 send SETTINGS frame ack:0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 send WINDOW_UPDATE frame sid:0, window:2147418112
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 read handler
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: 64
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 preface verified
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL buf copy: 27
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL buf copy: 13
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL buf copy: 9
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL to write: 49
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_write: 49
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free: 00005563F4C95410, unused: 3495
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free: 00005563F4E4F0A0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 reusable connection: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer del: 40: 1553443042390
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer add: 40: 180000:1553443162406
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 idle handler
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 posix_memalign: 00005563F4C95410:4096 @16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 read handler
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: 267
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 process http2 frame type:1 f:25 l:258 sid:1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 HEADERS frame sid:1 on 0 excl:1 weight:256
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 get indexed header name: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 get indexed header: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 hpack encoded string length: 14
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 add header to hpack table: ":authority: www.example.com"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http script copy: "Host: test.example.online
"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http script copy: "Connection: close
"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http script copy: ""
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http script copy: ""
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http script copy: ""
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http script copy: ""
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http proxy header: "cache-control: max-age=0"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http proxy header: "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http proxy header: "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http proxy header: "dnt: 1"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http proxy header: "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http proxy header: "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http proxy header: "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http proxy header:
"GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: test.example.online
Connection: close
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
dnt: 1
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8

"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 posix_memalign: 00005563F4CCC5A0:4096 @16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http cleanup add: 00005563F4CCC5C0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 get rr peer, try: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 get rr peer, current: 00005563F4DCC798 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 stream socket 42
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 epoll add connection: fd:42 ev:80002005
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 connect to [2001:1690:100:800::4]:443, fd:42 #8435
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream connect: -2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 posix_memalign: 00005563F4D66C30:128 @16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer add: 42: 60000:1553443042411
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http finalize request: -4, "/?" a:1, c:2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http request count:2 blk:0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 frame complete pos:00005563F4F1000B end:00005563F4F1000B
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer del: 40: 1553443162406
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream request: "/?"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream send request handler
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 malloc: 00005563F4E65870:72
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 upstream SSL server name: "test.example.online"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 set session: 00005563F4E3EB60
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 tcp_nodelay
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL handshake handler: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL: TLSv1.3, cipher: "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLSv1.3 Kx=any Au=any Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 save session: 00005563F4D0A470
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 old session: 00005563F4E3EB60
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL buf copy: 435
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL to write: 435
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_write: 435
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer del: 42: 1553443042411
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer add: 42: 60000:1553443042414

==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: accept on [::]:443, ready: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: posix_memalign: 00005563F4D0A770:512 @16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8436 accept: [2001:1690:100:800::4]:54472 fd:43
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8436 event timer add: 43: 60000:1553443042412
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8436 reusable connection: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8436 epoll add event: fd:43 op:1 ev:80002001
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8436 http check ssl handshake
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8436 http recv(): 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8436 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8436 SSL server name: "test.example.online"

==> /var/log/nginx/example_website_error.log <==
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream process header
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 malloc: 00005563F4DB8F90:4096
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream request: "/?"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream dummy handler
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream request: "/?"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream process header
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL renegotiation
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [notice] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL renegotiation disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.126.45.75, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2001:1690:100:800::4]:443/", host: "www.example.com"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http next upstream, 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free rr peer 2 4
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [warn] 8496#8496: *8434 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.126.45.75, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2001:1690:100:800::4]:443/", host: "www.example.com"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free rr peer failed: 00005563F4DCC798 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 close http upstream connection: 42
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_shutdown: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer del: 42: 1553443042414
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 get rr peer, try: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 get rr peer, current: 00005563F4DCC6F8 -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 stream socket 42
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 epoll add connection: fd:42 ev:80002005
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 connect to 84.241.175.19:443, fd:42 #8438
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream connect: -2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 posix_memalign: 00005563F4E8CB30:128 @16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer add: 42: 60000:1553443042427
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 read handler
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: 9
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 process http2 frame type:4 f:1 l:0 sid:0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 frame complete pos:00005563F4F0FF09 end:00005563F4F0FF09
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream request: "/?"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream send request handler
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 malloc: 00005563F4E4A700:72
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 upstream SSL server name: "test.example.online"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 set session: 00005563F4E491C0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 tcp_nodelay
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_get_error: 2

==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: accept on 0.0.0.0:443, ready: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: posix_memalign: 00005563F4E02160:512 @16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8439 accept: 84.241.175.19:58052 fd:43
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8439 event timer add: 43: 60000:1553443042429
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8439 reusable connection: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8439 epoll add event: fd:43 op:1 ev:80002001
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8439 http check ssl handshake
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8439 http recv(): 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8439 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8439 SSL server name: "test.example.online"

==> /var/log/nginx/example_website_error.log <==
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL handshake handler: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL: TLSv1.3, cipher: "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLSv1.3 Kx=any Au=any Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 save session: 00005563F4E3EB60
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 old session: 00005563F4E491C0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream send request
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream send request body
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 chain writer buf fl:0 s:435
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 chain writer buf fl:1 s:0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 chain writer in: 00005563F4CCC640
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 malloc: 00005563F4D6E3B0:80
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 malloc: 00005563F4E70BA0:16384
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL buf copy: 435
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL to write: 435
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_write: 435
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer del: 42: 1553443042427
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer add: 42: 60000:1553443042443
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream process header
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream request: "/?"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream dummy handler
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream request: "/?"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http upstream process header
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL renegotiation
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [notice] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL renegotiation disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.126.45.75, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://84.241.175.19:443/", host: "www.example.com"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http next upstream, 2
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free rr peer 1 4
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [warn] 8496#8496: *8434 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.126.45.75, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://84.241.175.19:443/", host: "www.example.com"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free rr peer failed: 00005563F4DCC6F8 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 finalize http upstream request: 502
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 finalize http proxy request
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 SSL_shutdown: 1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 close http upstream connection: 42
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free: 00005563F4E70BA0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free: 00005563F4D6E3B0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free: 00005563F4E4A700
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 free: 00005563F4E8CB30, unused: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 event timer del: 42: 1553443042443
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http finalize request: 502, "/?" a:1, c:1
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http special response: 502, "/?"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 xslt filter header
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 header filter
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 output header: ":status: 502"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 output header: "server: nginx"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 output header: "date: Sun, 24 Mar 2019 15:56:22 GMT"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 output header: "content-type: text/html"
2019/03/24 16:56:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8434 http2 output header: "content-length: 568"
```

**Upstream logs**

```
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL handshake handler: 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 ssl new session: 487D1A42:32:168
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 ssl new session: EDD4C86C:32:168
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL: TLSv1.3, cipher: "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLSv1.3 Kx=any Au=any Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 reusable connection: 1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http wait request handler
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 posix_memalign: 00005563F4E52060:512 @16
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 malloc: 00005563F4E03870:1024
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL_read: 435
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 posix_memalign: 00005563F4D94030:4096 @16
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http process request line
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http request line: "GET / HTTP/1.0"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http uri: "/"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http args: ""
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http exten: ""
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 posix_memalign: 00005563F4D611F0:4096 @16
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http process request header line
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "Host: test.example.com"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "Connection: close"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "cache-control: max-age=0"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "dnt: 1"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header: "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http header done
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 epoll add connection: fd:47 ev:80002005
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 connect to unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock, fd:47 #8732
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http finalize request: -4, "/index.php?" a:1, c:3
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http request count:3 blk:0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http finalize request: -4, "/index.php?" a:1, c:2
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http request count:2 blk:0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http run request: "/index.php?"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/index.php"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http upstream recv(): 0 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http upstream request: "/index.php?"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http upstream dummy handler
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http run request: "/index.php?"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http upstream check client, write event:0, "/index.php"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [info] 8496#8496: *8731 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream, client: 2001:1690:100:800::4, server: test.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "test.example.com"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 finalize http upstream request: 499
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 finalize http fastcgi request
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 free rr peer 1 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 close http upstream connection: 47
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 free: 00005563F4EB1430, unused: 48
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 event timer del: 47: 1553444602755
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http finalize request: 499, "/index.php?" a:1, c:1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http close request
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 http log handler

==> /var/log/nginx/example_test_access.log <==
2001:1690:100:800::4 - - [24/Mar/2019:17:13:22 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"

==> /var/log/nginx/example_test_error.log <==
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 close http connection: 46
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 SSL_shutdown: -1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8731 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 SSL handshake handler: 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 ssl new session: 470148A8:32:167
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 ssl new session: 6BA2403E:32:168
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 SSL: TLSv1.3, cipher: "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLSv1.3 Kx=any Au=any Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 reusable connection: 1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http wait request handler
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 malloc: 00005563F4D33400:1024
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 SSL_read: 435
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 SSL_read: -1
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 reusable connection: 0
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http process request line
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http request line: "GET / HTTP/1.0"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http process request header line
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "Host: test.example.com"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "Connection: close"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "cache-control: max-age=0"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "dnt: 1"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header: "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http header done
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 event timer del: 42: 1553444062788
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 test location: "/"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 test location: ~ "^/index\.php(/|$)"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 test location: ~ "\.php$"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http run request: "/index.php?"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http upstream check client, write event:0, "/index.php"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [info] 8496#8496: *8734 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream, client: 84.241.175.19, server: test.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "test.example.com"
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 finalize http upstream request: 499
2019/03/24 17:13:22 [debug] 8496#8496: *8734 http finalize request: 499, "/index.php?" a:1, c:1
```

Comment: Hm, yes it does appear that the upstream server did something unexpected. Check the logs on that server.

Comment: I've added the upstream logs. This log seems to indicate that the client closed the connection. Possibly because of the SSL renegotiation I think. I'm really wondering why it needs to do that (and why it doesn't when proxying from my local machine).

Comment: Hm, I see that your upstream server tried to send a request onward to php-fpm and got an EAGAIN error back. `http upstream recv(): 0 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)` That's when things appear to have gone wrong. It's time to take a close look at that server to see if anything at all is out of place.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Just one remark, the same error occurs when using the working localhost proxy (so it might be unrelated I guess).

Comment: Oh and one more thing, it fails on ANY https upstream. Also for example on example:com:443.

Comment: Is either of these servers behind a network firewall that does deep packet inspection?

Comment: Not that I know of, just basic iptables.

Comment: what of removing the proxy_ssl stuffs?? in that block??

Comment: I added that for SSL handshaking. That didn't work because the upstream name would be passed as the server name, in this case: example. Which in turn does not match any certificate on the upstream server.